# How to installi my app in windows phone mobile?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Hi i'm new in creating windows phone app, can you tell me how can i install my app in my mobile with windows phone 7 ?

Comment: Is supposed to be register developer to deploy my application in windows phone. I just wanna to deploy my application in my phone not to others ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the only way is to [join the developer program](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/membership) for an annual subscription cost of USD $99. The [ChevronWP7](http://www.chevronwp7.com/) team are supposedly working on releasing an official USD $9 unlock for homebrewers, but there's no word on when that will be available.

[Installing the tools](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/getting_started) will allow you to run the application on the emulator to test it, but the afore mentioned membership is required to test on your phone or publish on the marketplace.

Answer (score 1):

Deploy it using the *Application Deployment* program, or from within Visual Studio. You need to be a registered developer to do this. It costs $99 / year.

(I guess you aren't, since you otherwise wouldn't be asking)

Comment: Is it supposed to be register developer to deploy my application in windows phone. I just wanna to deploy my application in my phone not to others ???

Comment: Yes, it's also necessary for your own phone. It's like on the iPhone, pay the $99 or enjoy playing with the emulator.

Comment: Thnx Jorgensen for your replies